# OpenCV can't be used in ROS

Tags: opencv

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have been trouble by opencv problems. I have planed to transport my windows's code into ROS, which I have tested by local video files. I found that ROS doesn't support local video files, until ffmpeg has been installed. And Checking my ubuntu that it had been installed, I find ROS didn't support local video files neither.

I reinstall my ffmpeg and my opencv2.2, which I find my ROS doesn't support opencv unluckily. I test my older packages, such as [gencam_cu](http://www.ros.org/wiki/gencam_cu). It all doesn't work, while it will works very well without opencv, like [usb_cam](http://www.ros.org/wiki/usb_cam). I think my ROS system maybe disorder. So I reinstall my ROS refer to [ROS](http://www.ros.org/wiki/diamondback/Installation/Ubuntu).

But also it doesn't work. Especially, when uses "cvCaptureFromCAM" it can't get frames information. Try to find the reason for this problem, but I am so disappointed. I have been bored for many days. Could some one give me helps?

Given a example, codes below

```
Class UsbCamNode {Public :


ros::NodeHandle &node_;
sensor_msgs::Image img_;

std::string video_device_name_;
std::string io_method_name_;
int image_width_, image_height_;
std::string pixel_format_name_;

ros::Time next_time_;
int count_;

IplImage* src;
IplImage* src_canny;
CvCapture* capture;

image_transport::Publisher image_pub;

UsbCamNode(ros::NodeHandle &node):node_(node)
{
    src=NULL;
    capture=NULL;

    image_transport::ImageTransport it(node);

    image_pub=it.advertise("image_raw",1);
    int camera_num=0;
    ros::NodeHandle nh("~");
    nh.getParam("camera_index",camera_num);
    printf("%d",camera_num);
    
    if(NULL==(capture=cvCaptureFromCAM(camera_num)))
    {
        printf("\nError on cvCaptureFromCAM");
    }
    if(NULL==(src=cvQueryFrame(capture)))
    {
        printf("\nError on cvQueryFrame");  
    }

    

    printf("Acquired image (%d/%d%)\n",src->width,src->height);
    printf("Channels (%d)\n",src->nChannels);
    printf("Depth (%d)\n",src->depth);

cvNamedWindow("Capture",CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
cvNamedWindow("Canny",CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
cvMoveWindow("Capture",60,70);
next_time_=ros::Time::now();
count_=0;
}

virtual ~UsbCamNode()
{
    cvReleaseCapture(&capture);

    cvDestroyWindow("Capture");
    cvDestroyWindow("Canny");
}

bool take_and_send_image()
{
    int key;
    if(NULL==(src=cvQueryFrame(capture)))
    {   
        printf("\nError on cvQueryFrame");
    }
    else
    {

        cvShowImage("Capture",src);
        src_canny=DoCanny(src);
        cvShowImage("Canny",src_canny);
        key=cvWaitKey(10);

    //fill image message
    fillImage(img_,"mono8",src_canny->height,src_canny->width,src_canny->nChannels*src_canny->width,src_canny->imageData);
    //publish
    image_pub.publish(img_);
    return true;
    }
}

bool spin()
{
    while(node_.ok())
    {   
          if(take_and_send_image())
      {
        count_++;
        ros::Time now_time=ros::Time::now();
        if(now_time>next_time_)
        {   
            std::cout<<count_<<"frames/sec at"<<now_time<<std::endl;
            count_=0;
            next_time_=next_time_+ros::Duration(1,0);
        }
      } else {
        ROS_ERROR("could not take the image");
        usleep(1000000);
        }
    }
    return true;
} };
```

And it will show the results that:
0
Error on cvCaptureFromCAM
Segmentation fault

More, I find my problems are similar with [dkst](http://answers.ros.org/question/1128/opencv-videocapture-not-working-in-diamondback). I try all my methods as possible as I can think,but I did solve these problems. So call for help here

Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10230/opencv-can%27t-be-used-in-ros/) by [Yongqiang Gao](https://answers.ros.org/users/162/yongqiang-gao/) on ROS Answers with karma: 133 on 2011-06-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You should compare the configuration flags that you used on your working version of OpenCV vs. the flags that ROS compiles with. The flags can be found in the [opencv2 makefile](https://code.ros.org/svn/ros-pkg/stacks/vision_opencv/trunk/opencv2/Makefile). For example, I'm guessing `cvCaptureFromCAM` requires perhaps v4l support or ffmpeg, but those are both turned off by the ROS OpenCV build.

If you do need to add other flags or turn those on, you can check out the `vision_opencv` stack from source onto your `ROS_PACKAGE_PATH`, modify the Makefile and recompile the stack.

---

Originally posted by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) with karma: 8406 on 2011-06-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) on 2011-07-22**:
You will need to checkout the vision_opencv stack for your ROS distro from source, get it on your package path and then edit the flags and build. It is not recommend to change the precompiled packages in /opt or you may encounter conflicts later.

**Comment by [Bruno Normande](https://answers.ros.org/users/560/bruno-normande/) on 2011-07-22**:
on ubuntu, i changed the vision_opencv/opencv2/MakeFile flags 'v4l' and 'ffmpeg' to ON, re-maked the stack with ' rosmake vision_opencv --pre-cleanbut' and cvCaptureFromCAM still returns null for me =/ (maybe it is 'couse my installation - from repository- is pre-compiled?

**Comment by [Yongqiang Gao](https://answers.ros.org/users/162/yongqiang-gao/) on 2011-06-11**:
Thanks to Eric, and my process is that i copy "vision_opencv" in ros which can't be recompiled into "~/", then I turn on "ffmpeg" and "v4l", and then I "make" it.  That is right?  Anyway, it is been solved. So happy. Thanks again.